# Evaluate the line integral $\int_{\gamma} (yz, 0 , xy) \cdot d \mathbf{r}$

Tags: integration, solution-verification

This question is from Exercise 8b from *A Second Course in Mathematical Analysis (J. C. Burkill, H. Burkill)*.

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be defined by $f(x,y,z) = (yz, 0 , xy)$. Let $\gamma$ be the helical path defined by $$x = a \cos t, y = b \sin t, z = ct, 0 \leq t \leq \pi/2.$$ Evaluate $\int_{\gamma} f.$

I have attempted it as follows. I write $$\mathbf{r}(t) = (a \cos t, b \sin t, ct)$$
and obtain $$\mathbf{r'}(t) = (-a \sin t, b \cos t, c).$$

I also have $f(\mathbf{r}(t)) = (bct \sin t, 0 , ab \sin t \cos t)$ and so $$f(\mathbf{r}(t)) \cdot \mathbf{r}'(t) = -abct \sin^ 2 t + abc \sin t \cos t.$$

I did it by hand and confirmed using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20-abc%20%28t%20sin%5E2%20t%20-%20sint%20cost%20%29%20dt%20from%200%20to%20pi%2F2) that the integral from $0$ to $\pi/2$ is equal to $$-abc(\pi^2 -4)/16.$$

However, the printed answer at the back of the book is $$abc \pi^2 /16.$$

May I please ask where I went wrong here? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your result is correct!

Comment: Thank you for confirming Robert! ^^